# array element duplicate count using convert array element to string matching the value and also get string value its possible?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, if-statement, match

```js
function count5numbers1(arr){
 const m1 = arr.toString().match(/[5]/g);
 if (typeof m1 === 'string' || m1 instanceof String){
      return "it's not a number";
    }else if(m1 === null){
      return  0;
    }else{
      return m1.length;
    }
}
console.log(count5numbers1([1,2,5,43]));
console.log(count5numbers1([1,2,3,5]));
console.log(count5numbers1([1,2,4,2]));
console.log(count5numbers1([2,4,54,15]));
console.log(count5numbers1([1,5,55,555]));
console.log(count5numbers1([6,3,2,1]));
console.log(count5numbers1(['notnumber,its a string']));
```

I'm getting an answer is:
[1,1,0,2,6,0,0]

But an expected answer is:
[1,1,0,2,6,0, it's not a number]

Comment: I don't see the connection with "duplicate count". Nothing in your code is doing anything to detect duplicates.

Comment: m1 holds the value returned from match and will never be a string....

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do. You want  to log ' it's not a number' when all the elements in the array are strings?

Comment: Like @MosheSommers said, [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array of matches or `null`, therefore your first `if` condition will never be true.

Comment: What are you looking for? Do you want to print NaN if there's *any* string in the array, or if the array is *all* strings?

Comment: Can the example not be just `console.log('notnumber,its a string'.match(/[5]/g))` ?  (Which, of course, displays `null`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns either an array or `null`, checking whether its type is a string will always yield false.

You need to check over each element of the original array, rather than the match result, if you're looking for whether it contains something that isn't a number.

For that, you can use:

```js
arr.some(e => typeof e != 'number')
```

This will get the type of each element, and then check whether that type is a number or not.

Here it is in your example:

```js
function count5numbers1(arr) {
  const m1 = arr.toString().match(/[5]/g);
  if (arr.some(e => typeof e != 'number')) {
    return "it's not a number";
  } else if (m1 === null) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return m1.length;
  }
}

console.log(count5numbers1([1, 2, 5, 43]));
console.log(count5numbers1([1, 2, 3, 5]));
console.log(count5numbers1([1, 2, 4, 2]));
console.log(count5numbers1([2, 4, 54, 15]));
console.log(count5numbers1([1, 5, 55, 555]));
console.log(count5numbers1([6, 3, 2, 1]));
console.log(count5numbers1(['notnumber,its a string']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the expression `arr.toString().match(/[5]/g)` only ever returns an array of "5"s or null, you might best be checking for the string before then, like this (I'm assuming you are only checking integers - if you are also expecting decimals you will need to change this):

```
function count5numbers1(arr) {
    const m = arr.toString().replace(/,/g, '');

    if (isNaN(m)) {
      return "it's not a number";
    }

    const m1 = arr.toString().match(/[5]/g);

    if(m1 === null) {
      return  0;
    } else {
      return m1.length;
    }
}
```